# lamp server configuration error: locally stored php file not opening in the browser

Tags: php, apache-httpd

I was learning how to configure LAMP server on Ubuntu machine. I was following the given website

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

I created the info.php file using

```
 sudo nano /var/www/info.php
```

to contain the following lines

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then having restarted the apache2 service using

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I used the  ifconfig command to find the inet address. The line in the output was

```
inet addr:192.168.64.129  Bcast:192.168.65.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
```

So, as per the instructions on the link, I typed the following in the address bar of Mozilla browser

```
http://192.168.64.129/info.php
```

The tutorial says the a web page similar to

https://assets.digitalocean.com/tutorial_images/HCQEu.png

should open but in my case, the page could not be loaded. The error I received is

```
The requested URL /info.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.64.129 Port 80
```

Where am I missing out on?

Comment: Did you add php as an index file too?

Comment: no...it wasn't there in the instructions

Comment: "After you answer yes to the prompt twice, PHP will install itself.  It may also be useful to add php to the directory index, to serve the relevant php index files:  sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf Add index.php to the beginning of index files."

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default DocumentRoot for apache is `/var/www/html`, so try moving your php file there by doing:

```
 sudo mv /var/www/info.php /var/www/html/
```

If apache then complains that it cannot read the file, try `sudo chmod a+r /var/www/html/info.php`.